# Amazon EC2 Servers getting frozen sporadically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04, digital-ocean

I've been working with Amazon EC2 servers for 3+ years and I noticed a recurrent behaviour: some servers get frozen sporadically (between 1 to 5 times by year).

- When this fact ocurs, I can't connect to server (tried http, mysql and ssh connections) till server be restarted.
- The server back to work after a restart.
- Sometimes the server goes online by 6+ months, sometimes the server get frozen about 1 month after a restart.
- All servers I noticed this behavior were micro instances (North Virginia and Sao Paulo).
- The servers have an ordinary Apache 2, Mysql 5, PHP 7 environment, with Ubuntu 16 or 18. The PHP/MySQL Web application is not CPU intensive and is not accessed by more than 30 users/hour.
- The same environment and application on Digital Ocean servers does NOT reproduce the behaviour (I have two digital ocean servers running uninterrupted for 2+ years).

I like Amazon EC2 Servers, mainly because Amazon has a lot of useful additional services (like SES), but this behaviour is really frustating. Sometimes I got customers calls complaining about systems down and I just need an instance restart to solve the problem.

Does anybody have a tip about solving this problem?

**UPDATE 1**

- They are t2.micro instances (1Gb RAM, 1 vCPU).
- MySQL SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES: pastebin.com/m65ieAAb

**UPDATE 2**

There is a CPU utilization peak in the logs, near the time when server was down. It was at 3AM. At this time there is a daily crontab task to make a database backup. But, considering this task runs everyday, why just sometimes it would make server get frozen?

Comment: hi Arivan, i believe your issue can be resolved better by asking AWS support instead of stackoverflow..

Comment: Do micro instances have suppport service?

Comment: well, i'm not really sure, but it wont hurt to try. anyway, you can contact some people via IRC on `##aws` channel in `freenode`. its unofficial channel, but i believe you can get faster response there.

Comment: Have you considered autoscaling so instances are automatically replaced when they fail a health check?

Comment: Could it be a cpu utilization issue?

Comment: I looked cpu utilization chart and it have one peak near the time when server was down. It is strange because it was about 1am, when the systems is very little used. And why an CPU peak make the server goes down?

Comment: Are they t2 or t3 instance types? If so what do the CPU credits look like?

Comment: When it occurs have you looked "Get System Logs" and "Get Screenshot" for errors?

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WaltDe Sorry, I haven't. But I will give a try next time server goes down.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I updated the question, but I didnt get the point in provide "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST" or "top" results since these comands are very circumstantial. There is not a prevalent query/proccess, basically mysql goes top (and some queries are executed) when there is some user using the system. – Arivan Bastos 15 mins ago

Comment: It could be a memory related issue.  Check to see how swap is configured between the Digital Ocean and the EC2 instances.  Also, take a look at upgrading to the t3 or t3a types?  For the same micro size you get 2 VCPUs.  I also hear less mystery problems on the t3 over the t2.

Comment: @ArivanBastos You will not find in this URL that this AWS model is meant for production database. https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/t2/  At 2-3 AM, it is likely AWS is attempting to back up all supported servers.

Comment: @ArivanBastos SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; would reveal the extent of PID's hanging around longer than necessary (maybe SLEEPING), the top would reveal your swap availability and use, the ulimit -a would reveal Open Files from OS perspective, the iostat -xm 5 3 would reveal your core count.  SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; results are needed to go with SGV already posted for workload analysis completion.  Is your data storage on HDD, SSD or NVME?

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen this exact issue, but on any cloud platform I assume any instance can fail at any time, so we design for failure. For example we have autoscaling on all customer facing instances. Anytime an instance fails, it is automatically replaced.

If a customer is calling to advise you a server is down, you may need to consider more automated methods of monitoring instance health and take automated action to recover the instance.

CloudWatch also has server recovery actions available that can be trigger if certain metric thresholds are reached.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, but one point of my question is: why is the instance failing with a basic system when an equivalent instance in digital ocean does not presents a similar problem?

Comment: Understood. Are there no indications in the logs or cloud watch cpu metrics?

Comment: There is one cpu usage peak near the time when server was down. But, can a cpu usage peak make the server get frozen?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Especially with burstable instance types.

Comment: Do all the events correlate with CPU spikes?